# Make Windows 7 Explorer details divider lines wider?

Tags: windows-7, explorer

Is it possible to widen the draggable dividing lines between the Details view column headings in Win 7 Explorer?  I'm referring to the column headers with "Name", "Date modified", "Type", "Size", etc.  The dividers between these are so fine that I frequently end up dragging the columns around instead of resizing the column.